# JSON Accessing inner content

Tags: java, json

I'm fairly new to JSON and I'm trying to understand how to get information from it. Suppose I have the following exert,

```
{
    "a": {
        "num": 1,
    },
    "b": {
         "num": 3,
    },
    "c": {
         "num": 2,
    }
}
```

Now I know I can get 'num' by making a call as json.getJSONObject("a"); however is there a way which I can access them such as elements as an array? Where position 0 would return "num: 1", position 1 would return "num:3", etc? Sorry for the poor title, I'm not sure what this exact problem is called.

Comment: No, that's not how you traverse JSON objects. Use a JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a JSON array like:

```
[
  {"num": 1},
  {"num": 2},
  {"num": 3},
]
```

Or you can have an array inside of an object. It will look like

```
{
  "obj": [
      {"num": 1},
      {"num": 2},
      {"num": 3},
  ]
}
```

and the code to access an object by index will be:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(<your-json-as-string);
json.getJSONObject("obj").getJSONArray.get(<index>);
```

Comment: The problem I have is the JSONObject I am getting isn't constantly named "obj", each "sub-section"? (not sure if that's the name) is named something else. So one part might be "obj", another "obj1", etc. so I'm not sure how to loop through and store the values inside of it.